# Render a table with the number of columns and rows depending on the container dimensions

Tags: html, css

The HTML "Table" tag allows us to display data with a fixed number of columns and rows. But there are situations where the number of columns and rows should vary according to the browser's window. For instance, if each cell occupies 200 x 100 px, we could have 4 columns when the container has a width of 900, but only 2 with a width of 450:

"wide" window:

```
[ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4]
[ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8]
[ 9][10][11][12]
```

"cellphone":

```
[ 1][ 2]
[ 3][ 4]
[ 5][ 6]
[ 7][ 8]
[ 9][10]
[11][12]
```

How is the best way to render this?

Is it possible, without javascript, to render this using the table tag? or using CSS over divs?

Answer (score 0):

Without entering the never-ending argument between using tables or CSS, for the situation where the number of columns and rows are dependent of the container, the javascript-less solution seems to be using DIVs. The following approach uses the "float" css attribute.

CSS:

```
.container{
    ...
}
.dynamicTable{
    ...
}
.dynamicTable div{      
    width:200px;
    float:left; 
    ...
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="dynamicTable">
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    ...
</div>
</div>
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/sLb2uss6/